# Upgrade Linux Firmware

Tags: linux, firmware

I am using KDE Neon which is currently based on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am fairly accustomed to update kernel (currently running 4.10 without issues). The internet has many instructions on how to update kernel, delete unused ones.

However what strikes me is why is it nowhere mentioned to update the firmware too? apt search linux-firmware says it's at 1.157.8 whereas for Ubuntu

http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/linux-firmware

1.163 would be the latest, not to mention the firmware files from the individual hardware providers.

As I have sporadic WIFI issues after suspend to RAM I wonder if a firmware update, much like a kernel upgrade is "safe". I am asking as there are many resources mentioning kernel update (mainline) but no mention to update the firmware.

PS: Please don't ask me to try, unless there is a save way to revert back to an older version without the need to re-install Linux. I am past the point to be interested to mess a whole day to get a working system.

Comment: check the [changelog for the package](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.163/changelog) and look for your wifi chipset in the versions after 1.157.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that they had problems with WiFi with the latest version of firmware (amongst other issues), and this is a regression to a more stable version.

See: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/bugs?package_name=linux-firmware

Then (say): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1647826 (or any of the WiFI-related issues)
and then compare with the list of files in the current (your) firmware version at your referenced link.

Hope that helps (and fixes your WiFi issues) 
Cheers! :)

Comment: By the way, since I reverted to the earlier firmware my Ubuntu 16.04LTS (with a KDE front end) has finally allowed me to reboot etc. correctly. Something else that changed, possibly due to the firmware.